# Is it possible to return a Dutch rental car to a different location in Amsterdam?

Tags: car-rentals, netherlands

I plan to rent a car at Schiphol and may need to return it to the Enterprise auto rental or SIXT in Station Centraal Downtown.  If I pivot and decide to return it to downtown and not the airport (or vice versa), I am wondering what, if any, problems this will cause.

Comment: Did you try asking the car rental company? There is usually a fee for dropping the car off at a different station.

Comment: Good question.   There is no email to ask the question (always best to have response in writing), but I did try booking a different return station and the price is double ($50 -> $100)

Comment: It is a short travel time between them, I do not see the problem with traveling back to the location you collected the car and use train (and maybe bus) to get to the other one. But just call the company, sometimes they have a stream of cars going one way and are wiling to wave the extra fee if go the other way around. (Brother used to work for a car rental at Schiphol.)

Comment: Good comment: thanks.  When travelling time is at a premium, so if I can avoid standing in a line or avoid unnecessary transit it is worth it to me.  I have to drop her and luggage at the hotel near Centraal and would need to go back and forth to the airport.

Comment: I would imagine (but can't show) that a last-minute change of drop-off location is unlikely to be allowed, as it interferes with the rental company's logistics. 
They are likely to have the car booked to another customer later that day. Although they will have spare cars in case of accidents, or late returns, they do not want to encourage returns to other locations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are serving by SIXT (which I used, that's why talking about this one, not because it's the best one) rental company the answer is yes, you can drop of the car in any of their office (most of the rental companies allow it), BUT if you going to drop it of in another city you get it you have to pay much more money even if your route known beforehand. Sometimes it costs more even if the offices are different in the same city.

Comment: Thanks for the good insight.  I rented from the airport at SIXT and ended up returning at the airport because Schiphol has a train station and hotel in the airport.